# Disable one input when other input is filled out

Tags: jsf

I want to disable other input tag if p:calendar value is entered

```
  <p:calendar id="someDate" value=.... binding="#{bind}" />
```

for example to disable p:selectOneMenu but this disables it permanently.

```
 <p:selectOneMenu id="selectManu" value=... disabled="#{bind!=null}" >
```

How to disable it only if p:calendar have value ??

Comment: You may want to go with what is said to be *cross field validation* but where do you need this kind of unusual requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the source component ajax-update the target component on the desired events, and let the `disabled` attribute of the target component check if the `value` of the source component is `not empty`.

So,

```
<p:calendar ... value="#{bean.date}">
    <p:ajax event="valueChange" update="menu" />
    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" update="menu" />
</p:calendar>
...
<p:selectOneMenu id="menu" ... disabled="#{not empty bean.date}" />
```

The `binding` is not necessary in this construct. If you *really* want to use it, then you should be checking the component's `value` attribute, not the component itself (which is obviously never `null`).

```
<p:calendar binding="#{calendar}" ...>
    <p:ajax event="valueChange" update="menu" />
    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" update="menu" />
</p:calendar>
...
<p:selectOneMenu id="menu" ... disabled="#{not empty calendar.value}" />
```

If you want to learn more about `binding`, head to [How does the 'binding' attribute work in JSF? When and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911158/how-does-the-binding-attribute-work-in-jsf-when-and-how-should-it-be-used)